Cyclic HTTP 400 errors in Spring Boot application using Feign client for scheduled tasks
I am encountering a cyclic error pattern in a Spring Boot application utilizing a Feign client for inter-service communication. This issue specifically arises with scheduled tasks that make HTTP POST requests at one-minute intervals. The behavior observed is distinctly cyclic: if the application starts and the first scheduled request returns an HTTP 400 (Bad Request), all subsequent requests in that session continue to return HTTP 400 errors. If I terminate the process and restart the application, the behavior reverses — this time, all requests succeed without any errors. This pattern repeats every time the application is restarted: a session starts with errors will consistently have errors, and a session that starts correctly will run correctly throughout.
This cyclical problem persists without any changes to the server, which is configured to handle requests consistently.
Example Scenario:
Start the application - the first request returns HTTP 400.
All following requests in this session also return HTTP 400.
Kill the application process and restart.
This time, the first request after restarting is successful.
All subsequent requests in this new session are successful.
Kill and restart the process, and the issue from step 1 repeats.
Here is the simplified version of my client and server code involved in the communication:
    @FeignClient(name = "withdraw-feign-client", url = "127.0.0.1:8081")
    public interface WithdrawFeignClient {
        @PostMapping("/withdraw/pullWithdraw")
        @ResponseBody
        CommonResult<List<WithdrawVO>> pullWithdraw(@RequestBody RequestData<PullWithdrawReq> req);
    }


    RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
    requestData.setChain(Chain.FIL);
    requestData.setDataString("123");
    requestData.setData(pullWithdrawReq);
    CommonResult<List<com.dhlfy.financerpcclient.WithdrawVO>> result =     withdrawFeignClient.pullWithdraw(requestData);


    @PostMapping("/pullWithdraw")
    public CommonResult<List<WithdrawVO>> pullWithdraw(@RequestBody RequestData<PullWithdrawReq> req) {
        String k = formatParma(req);
        PullWithdrawReq withdrawReq = JSONObject.parseObject(k, PullWithdrawReq.class);
        checkSign(withdrawReq);
        return CommonResult.success(withdrawService.pullWithdraw(req.getChain().name(), withdrawReq));
    }


400 errors come from the server. Are there any error logs is the server? There's nothing that would indicate anything from the code snippets you posted.

I had almost the same problem but faced in exactly same scenario: Firing POST HTTP requests using Feign from a scheduled task. The only difference in my case was that the HTTP calls from a @SpringBootTest would always return 200 whereas all calls from within the scheduled task would only return 400s.
I placed a breakpoint right before sending the data over the socket (L100: feign.SynchronousMethodHandler) and captured the 2 stacktraces. Comparing them, apart from the very first levels there didn't seem to be any differences in the call stack which baffled me for quite some time.
Being clueless at that stage, I then realized I hadn't configured any specific client implementation (Apache, OkHttp, etc) so I tried to specify one and in the configuration and observe the behaviour. I went with OkHttp and the following configuration:
pom.xml
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
       <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>13.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
       <version>1.18.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
       <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

HttpClientsConfig.java
package house.x1337.livefeed.config;

import feign.Client;
import feign.codec.Decoder;
import feign.codec.Encoder;
import feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder;
import feign.jackson.JacksonEncoder;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {
    "house.x1337.livefeed.client"
})
public class HttpClientsConfig {
    @Bean
    public Decoder decoder() {
        return new JacksonDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new JacksonEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(new OkHttpClient());
    }
}

All then magically started to work. This is one of the strangest issues I've seen cause I never got to the bottom of it. Initially I thought it's something to do with the Auto-Configuration lifecycle or thread-level context. Debugged a lot of components in those 2 areas but nothing obvious.
Worth mentioning I was able to reproduce the 400 on Postman and on demand by removing the "Host" header from the request. This is a restricted header which is supposed to be set implicitly in the runtime by the JVM. This is a known issue in Feign as discussed here: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/747. It could be that depending on the project's configuration, this header for some reason is not sent over the socket. This is a core header most if not all servers expect to dispatch the request appropriately to the downstream and if absent, the request is rejected as invalid.
